# Unable to deserialize from xml file

Tags: c#, xmlreader, xmlserializer

explained.Getting exception when deserializing . Can anybody help me what has gone wrong for the reason. I have created a class for the data to be extracted from the xml file. But when deserialixing back to object I am getting exeption.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Body>
<n1:GetPlugStatusListResponse xmlns:n1="http://tempuri.org/SPSuiteWebService/StandService">
  <n1:GetPlugStatusListResponse xmlns:n2="http://tempuri.org/GetPlugStatusListResponse.xsd">
<n2:StoreList>
<n2:Store>  
<n2:AreaType>13</n2:AreaType>
<n2:AreaName>東京都</n2:AreaName>
<n2:StoreCd>91110002</n2:StoreCd>
</n2:Store>    
<n2:Store>
</n2:Store>
 ...
</n2:StoreList>




    public static List<Store> ParseStoreList(string fileName) 
      {

          // Init
          List<Store> listStoreList = new List<Store>();

              // Parse...
              using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fileName))
              {
                  XmlSerializer EventSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Store));


                  while (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("n2:Store"))
                  {
                      Store storeObject = (Store)EventSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader.ReadSubtree());
                      listStoreList.Add(storeObject);

                  }

                  xmlReader.Close();
              }




          // Return value
          return listStoreList;

      }

    public static List<PlugListData> ParsePlugList(string fileName)
    {
        // Init
        List<PlugListData> listPlugList = new List<PlugListData>();

        // Parse...
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fileName))
        {
            XmlSerializer EventSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Store));

            // Parse XML - "Event" nodes...
            while (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("n2:PlugStatus"))
            {
                PlugListData pluglistObject = (PlugListData)EventSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader.ReadSubtree());
                listPlugList.Add(pluglistObject);
            }

            // Cleanup...
            xmlReader.Close();
        }

        // Return value
        return listPlugList;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Now you should show the XML.

Comment: Error in XML document - line 9, column 12. Take a look there, there's something that breaks the XML format.

Comment: `XmlSerializer` actually gives **really** detailed error messages; you need to look at the `.InnerException`, and the `.InnerException.InnerException`, etc

Comment: The alias `n2` is not declared anywhere; that xml is basically meaningless... you should have `xmlns:n2="some urn"` (where "some urn" needs to match the namespace declared against `Store` etc. Ideally it would be good to see the xml and type definition here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Store));// create the serializer
TextReader reader = new StreamReader("n2:Store"); //read your text
object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);// create object

Store xmlData = (Store)obj;// access data from object
```